# How to get better error messages in a MAKE?

Tags: c++, debugging, makefile, php-extension

I run a `make` command on a CPP code. I get error messages like:
`/home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/sitel/build/entities.cpp: In function ‘void googleset_free_storage(void*)’:`
As can be seen, except showing me the entry point of the function with errors, it does not give me anymore data. Is there a flag or some other way to get proper error messages?

MakeFile -> I know it is big...

```
srcdir = /home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/build
builddir = /home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/build
top_srcdir = /home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/build
top_builddir = /home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/build
EGREP = /bin/grep -E
SED = /bin/sed
CONFIGURE_COMMAND = './configure' '--enable-entities'
CONFIGURE_OPTIONS = '--enable-entities'
SHLIB_SUFFIX_NAME = so
SHLIB_DL_SUFFIX_NAME = so
ZEND_EXT_TYPE = zend_extension
RE2C = exit 0;
AWK = gawk
ENTITIES_SHARED_LIBADD = -lstdc++
shared_objects_entities = entities.lo GoogleSet.lo
PHP_PECL_EXTENSION = entities
PHP_MODULES = $(phplibdir)/entities.la
PHP_ZEND_EX =
all_targets = $(PHP_MODULES) $(PHP_ZEND_EX)
install_targets = install-modules install-headers
prefix = /usr
exec_prefix = $(prefix)
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
prefix = /usr
phplibdir = /home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/build/modules
phpincludedir = /usr/include/php5
CC = cc
CFLAGS = -g -O2
CFLAGS_CLEAN = $(CFLAGS)
CPP = cc -E
CPPFLAGS = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2
CXXFLAGS_CLEAN = $(CXXFLAGS)
EXTENSION_DIR = /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
PHP_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/php
EXTRA_LDFLAGS =
EXTRA_LIBS =
INCLUDES = -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
LFLAGS =
LDFLAGS =
SHARED_LIBTOOL =
LIBTOOL = $(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool
SHELL = /bin/bash
INSTALL_HEADERS =
mkinstalldirs = $(top_srcdir)/build/shtool mkdir -p
INSTALL = $(top_srcdir)/build/shtool install -c
INSTALL_DATA = $(INSTALL) -m 644

DEFS = -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I$(top_builddir)/include -I$(top_builddir)/main -I$(top_srcdir)
COMMON_FLAGS = $(DEFS) $(INCLUDES) $(EXTRA_INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(PHP_FRAMEWORKPATH)

all: $(all_targets) 
    @echo
    @echo "Build complete."
    @echo "Don't forget to run 'make test'."
    @echo

build-modules: $(PHP_MODULES) $(PHP_ZEND_EX)

libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).la: $(PHP_GLOBAL_OBJS) $(PHP_SAPI_OBJS)
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=link $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) -rpath $(phptempdir) $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(PHP_RPATHS) $(PHP_GLOBAL_OBJS) $(PHP_SAPI_OBJS) $(EXTRA_LIBS) $(ZEND_EXTRA_LIBS) -o $@
    -@$(LIBTOOL) --silent --mode=install cp $@ $(phptempdir)/$@ >/dev/null 2>&1

libs/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).bundle: $(PHP_GLOBAL_OBJS) $(PHP_SAPI_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(MH_BUNDLE_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS_CLEAN) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) $(PHP_GLOBAL_OBJS:.lo=.o) $(PHP_SAPI_OBJS:.lo=.o) $(PHP_FRAMEWORKS) $(EXTRA_LIBS) $(ZEND_EXTRA_LIBS) -o $@ && cp $@ libs/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).so

install: $(all_targets) $(install_targets)

install-sapi: $(OVERALL_TARGET)
    @echo "Installing PHP SAPI module:       $(PHP_SAPI)"
    -@$(mkinstalldirs) $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(bindir)
    -@if test ! -r $(phptempdir)/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).$(SHLIB_DL_SUFFIX_NAME); then \
        for i in 0.0.0 0.0 0; do \
            if test -r $(phptempdir)/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).$(SHLIB_DL_SUFFIX_NAME).$$i; then \
                $(LN_S) $(phptempdir)/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).$(SHLIB_DL_SUFFIX_NAME).$$i $(phptempdir)/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).$(SHLIB_DL_SUFFIX_NAME); \
                break; \
            fi; \
        done; \
    fi
    @$(INSTALL_IT)

install-modules: build-modules
    @test -d modules && \
    $(mkinstalldirs) $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(EXTENSION_DIR)
    @echo "Installing shared extensions:     $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(EXTENSION_DIR)/"
    @rm -f modules/*.la >/dev/null 2>&1
    @$(INSTALL) modules/* $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(EXTENSION_DIR)

install-headers:
    -@if test "$(INSTALL_HEADERS)"; then \
        for i in `echo $(INSTALL_HEADERS)`; do \
            i=`$(top_srcdir)/build/shtool path -d $$i`; \
            paths="$$paths $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/$$i"; \
        done; \
        $(mkinstalldirs) $$paths && \
        echo "Installing header files:          $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/" && \
        for i in `echo $(INSTALL_HEADERS)`; do \
            if test "$(PHP_PECL_EXTENSION)"; then \
                src=`echo $$i | $(SED) -e "s#ext/$(PHP_PECL_EXTENSION)/##g"`; \
            else \
                src=$$i; \
            fi; \
            if test -f "$(top_srcdir)/$$src"; then \
                $(INSTALL_DATA) $(top_srcdir)/$$src $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/$$i; \
            elif test -f "$(top_builddir)/$$src"; then \
                $(INSTALL_DATA) $(top_builddir)/$$src $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/$$i; \
            else \
                (cd $(top_srcdir)/$$src && $(INSTALL_DATA) *.h $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/$$i; \
                cd $(top_builddir)/$$src && $(INSTALL_DATA) *.h $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/$$i) 2>/dev/null || true; \
            fi \
        done; \
    fi

PHP_TEST_SETTINGS = -d 'open_basedir=' -d 'output_buffering=0' -d 'memory_limit=-1'
PHP_TEST_SHARED_EXTENSIONS =  ` \
    if test "x$(PHP_MODULES)" != "x"; then \
        for i in $(PHP_MODULES)""; do \
            . $$i; $(top_srcdir)/build/shtool echo -n -- " -d extension=$$dlname"; \
        done; \
    fi; \
    if test "x$(PHP_ZEND_EX)" != "x"; then \
        for i in $(PHP_ZEND_EX)""; do \
            . $$i; $(top_srcdir)/build/shtool echo -n -- " -d $(ZEND_EXT_TYPE)=$(top_builddir)/modules/$$dlname"; \
        done; \
    fi`
PHP_DEPRECATED_DIRECTIVES_REGEX = '^(define_syslog_variables|register_(globals|long_arrays)?|safe_mode|magic_quotes_(gpc|runtime|sybase)?|(zend_)?extension(_debug)?(_ts)?)[\t\ ]*='

test: all
    -@if test ! -z "$(PHP_EXECUTABLE)" && test -x "$(PHP_EXECUTABLE)"; then \
        INI_FILE=`$(PHP_EXECUTABLE) -d 'display_errors=stderr' -r 'echo php_ini_loaded_file();' 2> /dev/null`; \
        if test "$$INI_FILE"; then \
            $(EGREP) -h -v $(PHP_DEPRECATED_DIRECTIVES_REGEX) "$$INI_FILE" > $(top_builddir)/tmp-php.ini; \
        else \
            echo > $(top_builddir)/tmp-php.ini; \
        fi; \
        INI_SCANNED_PATH=`$(PHP_EXECUTABLE) -d 'display_errors=stderr' -r '$$a = explode(",\n", trim(php_ini_scanned_files())); echo $$a[0];' 2> /dev/null`; \
        if test "$$INI_SCANNED_PATH"; then \
            INI_SCANNED_PATH=`$(top_srcdir)/build/shtool path -d $$INI_SCANNED_PATH`; \
            $(EGREP) -h -v $(PHP_DEPRECATED_DIRECTIVES_REGEX) "$$INI_SCANNED_PATH"/*.ini >> $(top_builddir)/tmp-php.ini; \
        fi; \
        TEST_PHP_EXECUTABLE=$(PHP_EXECUTABLE) \
        TEST_PHP_SRCDIR=$(top_srcdir) \
        CC="$(CC)" \
            $(PHP_EXECUTABLE) -n -c $(top_builddir)/tmp-php.ini $(PHP_TEST_SETTINGS) $(top_srcdir)/run-tests.php -n -c $(top_builddir)/tmp-php.ini -d extension_dir=$(top_builddir)/modules/ $(PHP_TEST_SHARED_EXTENSIONS) $(TESTS); \
    else \
        echo "ERROR: Cannot run tests without CLI sapi."; \
    fi

clean:
    find . -name \*.gcno -o -name \*.gcda | xargs rm -f
    find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o | xargs rm -f
    find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f 
    find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
    find . -name .libs -a -type d|xargs rm -rf
    rm -f libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).la $(SAPI_CLI_PATH) $(OVERALL_TARGET) modules/* libs/*

distclean: clean
    rm -f Makefile config.cache config.log config.status Makefile.objects Makefile.fragments libtool main/php_config.h stamp-h sapi/apache/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).module buildmk.stamp
    $(EGREP) define'.*include/php' $(top_srcdir)/configure | $(SED) 's/.*>//'|xargs rm -f

.PHONY: all clean install distclean test
.NOEXPORT:
entities.lo: /home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/build/entities.cpp
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=compile $(CXX)  -I. -I/home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/build $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS_CLEAN) $(EXTRA_CXXFLAGS)  -c /home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/build/entities.cpp -o entities.lo 
GoogleSet.lo: /home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/build/GoogleSet.cpp
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=compile $(CXX)  -I. -I/home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/build $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS_CLEAN) $(EXTRA_CXXFLAGS)  -c /home/itaymoav/dev/phpext/build/GoogleSet.cpp -o GoogleSet.lo 
$(phplibdir)/entities.la: ./entities.la
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=install cp ./entities.la $(phplibdir)

./entities.la: $(shared_objects_entities) $(ENTITIES_SHARED_DEPENDENCIES)
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=link $(CC) $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS_CLEAN) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath $(phplibdir) $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) $(shared_objects_entities) $(ENTITIES_SHARED_LIBADD)
```

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with g++ and is a problem with your makefile. Unfortunately you do not include the part of the makefile that is stripping the output so it is imposable to solve your problem with the given information.

Comment: @Loki Astari It is the default Make file that you get when you run the phpize + .configure

Comment: Does not change my opinion. The part of the makefile we need is not here. This mkaefile may be included from another makefile. But the bit were the compiler is called is not here and the default options would not strip the extra output.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to examine your `Makefile` and any rules files it includes.  Find the rule for compiling `.cpp` into `.o` and see what sort of filtering it is doing on your compile output.  If it is intentionally restricting the output of the compiler to make normal compiles less verbose it will probably have a flag you can set to override that.  The Linux kernel (and many related Makefiles) use a `QUIET` flag for this purpose, so you can do `make QUIET=''` to disable the terse output and see everything.

If the build rule is hiding errors there is probably a bug in it.  If you can find it and add it to your question someone may know how to fix it.

Comment: It is auto generated by phpize /.configure (Did I mention I am a nub in this?). My point is it is huge.

Answer (score 0):

The line you quoted is not the real error message. It is just the first of two lines. The following line contains the really interesting stuff.

And only in the rare case that there *isn't* a second line should you worry. Because then somebody wrapped the compiler to suppress some of its error messages.